# Select2 plugin (multiple select input) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to replicate a simple select2 example to display a multiple-select input field, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/.

Here is my code (`index.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#e1").select2();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<label>Select Locations</label>
    <select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

The result I get is:

[image]

I wrote the code in a simple text file and changed the extension to `.html`

I have tried both chrome and firefox, but get the same result.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the document is fully loaded, try to modify the content of your `script` tag to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#e1").select2();
});
```

Comment: Or move the script to the bottom of the page, which is best practice anyway.

Comment: @Tim I assume that should work too. But I guess `$(document).ready(function() { }` is more reliable.

Comment: If jquery, select2 and your markup are all loaded, you can just call `$("#e1").select2();` without waiting for document ready. Less code, quicker, and arguably more reliable.